# Python method that returns instance of class or subclass while keeping subclass attributes

Tags: python, inheritance, overwrite

I'm writing a Python class `A` with a method `square()` that returns a new instance of that class with its first attribute squared. For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def square(self):
        return self.__class__(self.x**2)
```

I would like to use this method in a subclass `B` so that it returns an instance of `B` with `x` squared but all additional attributes of `B` unchanged (i. e. taken from the instance). I can get it to work by overwriting `square()` like this:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(B, self).__init__(x)
        self.y = y

    def square(self):
        return self.__class__(self.x**2, self.y)
```

If I don't overwrite the `square()` method, this little code example will fail because I need to pass a value for `y` in the constructor of `B`:

```
#test.py

class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x 

    def square(self):
        return self.__class__(self.x**2)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(B, self).__init__(x)
        self.y = y 

    #def square(self):
    #    return self.__class__(self.x**2, self.y)

a = A(3)
a2 = a.square()
print(a2.x)
b = B(4, 5)
b2 = b.square()
print(b2.x, b2.y)
```

```
$ python test.py
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    b2 = b.square()
  File "test.py", line 6, in square
    return self.__class__(self.x**2)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Overwriting the method once isn't a problem. But `A` potentially has multiple methods similar to `square()` and there might be more sub(sub)classes. If possible, I would like to avoid overwriting all those methods in all those subclasses.

So my question is this:
Can I somehow implement the method `square()` in `A` so that it returns a new instance of the current subclass with `x` squared and all other attributes it needs for the constructor taken from `self` (kept constant)? Or do I have to go ahead and overwrite `square()` for each subclass?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a nutshell: if you need to construct a new instance, then you need to pass that new instance all the arguments it requires to be instantiated, and if that class you're instantiating varies, then yeah, each subclass will have to override the method to customise it as necessary. There's no real shortcut around that, unless your classes are pretty predictable and follow certain patterns, so reading existing attributes and passing them as kwargs to the constructor can be automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest implementing `.__copy__()` (and possibly `.__deepcopy__` as well) methods for both classes.

Then your `squared` can be simple method:

```
def squared(self):
    newObj = copy(self)
    newObj.x = self.x **2
    return newObj
```

It will work with inheritance, assuming all child classes have correctly implemented `__copy__` method.

EDIT: fixed typo with call to `copy()`

Full working example:

```
#test.py

from copy import copy


class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x 

    def square(self):
        newObj = copy(self)
        newObj.x = self.x **2
        return newObj

    def __copy__(self):
        return A(self.x)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(B, self).__init__(x)
        self.y = y 

    def __copy__(self):
        return B(self.x, self.y)

a = A(3)
a2 = a.square()
print(a2.x)
b = B(4, 5)
b2 = b.square()
print(b2.x, b2.y)
```

Comment: That's a very handy solution and it works perfectly for what I'm doing! I would upvote it if I had more reputation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

check if the object contains `y` then return the right class instance:

```py
class A:
    x: int
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def square(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'y'):
            return self.__class__(self.x ** 2, self.y)
        
        return self.__class__(self.x**2)


class B(A):
    y: int
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(B, self).__init__(x)
        self.y = y

    # def square(self):
    #     return self.__class__(self.x**2, self.y)
```

Comment: Are you gonna do that check for every other possible attribute child class might have?